# Windows Phone or Windows Phone Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have just installed Windows 8.1 and then installed Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

I tried to create a Windows Phone app and found out that there are two ways of creating it (in fact 3 if you count Universal Apps if I am not wrong)

1. Windows Phone
2. Windows Phone Silverlight

Can someone please tell me what exactly is the difference between these two? I read a couple of articles but still don't understand and this whole thing is very confusing.

When I tried to create a Windows Phone Silverlight project then it asked me whether I want to target 8.0 or 8.1.

When I tried to create Windows Phone project then it asked me to get a Developer license and didn't ask about version 8.0 or 8.1.

What shall I chose if my aim is to create an application for mobile devices (tablet/phones) that will run on maximum devices running Windows Phone 8 version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 Store VS Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348457/windows-phone-8-1-store-vs-windows-phone-8-1-silverlight)

Comment: Seems like a duplicate, but still... _Windows Phone_ is basically the new platform. It is not supported on Windows Phone versions prior to 8.1. _Windows Phone_ is basically the Windows Phone part of a Universal app. You can easily convert from WP to Universal app (it's one click away). If you want to support older WP versions - you need Silverlight. If you want to support tablets - you need the new one. I'd suggest you go with the new one - Windows Phone.

Comment: Also possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544762/in-windows-phone-8-1-what-is-the-differance-between-windows-phone-project-and-si/23545031#23545031

Comment: @yasen Ok but won't using Windows Phone be a disadvantage at this stage because most of share is held by Windows Phone 8 and not 8.1?

Comment: As I said in my last comment on Karthik's answer - WP8.1 has 50% share. By the time you have a solid stable working app, it will have even more. But that is a valid consideration, so it's up to you. If what you'll be doing is work-related (you're not your boss) - discuss it with the senior developers/project managers. If not - I still think you should go for the new platform.

Comment: HI Yasin,

"Seems like a duplicate, but still... .....".

Your above comment looks very confusing. What you mean by Windows Phone versions not supported before 8.1?. Could you please phrase it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 Silverlight is the older UI on Windows Phone 8. WinRT XAML is used for Windows Store Apps(these are Universal Apps). Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight is a bit different as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642080(v=vs.105).aspx).

Windows Phone Silverlight, although older, is better in some ways. If your aim is to develop an app that is targeted only for phones and that doesn't have any use getting ported to Win8/RT, go with Silverlight. Background Audio is a mess in WinRT. Speech Recognition with Cortana is worse.

The controls of WinRT XAML are buggy. For example, there is a clear performance degradation of `MapControl` in WinRT XAML, whereas, in Silverlight, this is smoother.

On the other hand, Windows Store Apps have .NET Native, which converts C# to native C++ code, resulting in performance gains.

For a beginner, I would advise starting with Windows Phone 8 Silverlight apps.

Comment: I don't really understand why is everybody advising people who are just starting to use an older technology, that will likely get phased out in time, instead of learning the new APIs and the new platform that also works on both tablets and phones (unlike the old one which is for phones only). So, I respectfully disagree with this answer.

Comment: I must agree with @yasen on this one, unless you need one of the API:s only available for Silverlight, WinRT is the better choice. And I don't Think that it is that much harder to get started with than Silverlight apps.

Comment: He kinda has a point.  I made a very simple app, and I swear 30% of my development time was spent working around the numerous, serious bugs in the mapping APIs.  But the same thing happened in 8.0 as well; many people elected to use the 7.1 map control because the 8.0 one was such a giant step backwards.  Maybe the lesson is use [version] - 1 for maps?

Comment: @yasen @johan-falk WP8 has `WebClient` which can quickly download a string (json maybe), which is good for a beginner. WinRT doesn't have a `WebClient`, but a `HttpClient`, which is tougher and more complex for a beginner to handle. One more point, in the recently leaked Win10 build, it ran Windows Phone apps (not sure SL or RT app).. So, maybe WP8 Silverlight app wont die immediately

Comment: Ok so what I could gather from this discussion is, Windows Phone is the future and Windows Phone Silverlight is past. To target maximum devices one need to start with Windows Phone. Correct? But then what's this Universal app thing?

Comment: @KarthikNishanth I could give you counter examples. Both platforms have some issues and need workarounds sometimes. So why work around an older platform? It seems better to learn the tricks of the new one. At least that's how I see it. I highly doubt they'll start supporting Silverlight on the Desktop, but SL for phone may not die soon, yes.

Comment: @FrankMartin Mostly correct. If you want to target more phones, you may prefer Silverlight. Based on stats from November - WP8.1 had 50% share and WP8.0 - 33%. But versions prior to 8.1 are getting less and less relevant. On the other hand, if you want to support tablets - go for _Windows Phone_. About Universal app - it's an app that has 3 projects - one for phone, which is exactly the same as a _Windows Phone_ project, one for desktop/tablets (with Windows 8.1) and one with files shared between the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone Silverlight is the "old" platform that WP8.0 apps are built on.  It asked you to target 8.0 or 8.1 because WP8.1 has a hybrid mode that lets you build WP8.1 apps but still have access to the Sliverlight API if you had a whole lot of legacy code you didn't want to port over just yet.

Windows Phone is the (mostly) universal platform for WP8.1 that is based on Windows Runtime.

Comment: So it means if I want my app to run on maximum devices, I shall develop it in Windows Phone Silverlight?

Comment: No, Silverlight is the *old* platform.  It will never run on tablets.

Comment: You mean on Windows 8/8.1 based tablets or Surface?

Comment: To run on Windows 8/8.1 devices as well as on phones you need to target WinRT/8.1 universal app. If you use the universal app template you can only target WinRT, which means your app will run on Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 (tablets, desktops, laptops, etc.); it won't run on WP8 or earlier. There are still quite a lot of users on WP8, but not many on WP7. If you want to target PCs & tablets - go WinRT universal. If you want to target only phones target Windows Phone 8 or 8.1. If you choose 8.1 WinRT is the future-proof option and will let you port more easily to Windows in future.