# What is the difference between Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

What is the difference between Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight?

Which Option(Project) is best suitable for new app development? Also please provide Pros and Cons of each option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 Store VS Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348457/windows-phone-8-1-store-vs-windows-phone-8-1-silverlight)

Answer (score -2):

So basically silverlight is used for browser based applications, you can relate to macromedia flash, it depends of what type of app you have in mind...if you would like to have your app available on all devices I suggest you use MVVM (model, view, view model) architecture so that you are able to share most of your code.

I suggest you look into Lex.DB as for database engine for your app since it works on both desktop and mobile with the same code.

You may encounter some trouble using aync tasks in silverlight, but still there are some 3rd parties libraries which helps with that.

So basically there arent any pros and cons since they are not platform related.

Comment: Thanks Johan for the answer. Actualy i want to know more about the difference between Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight Projects.

Comment: hi you are correct...windows phone silverlight toolkit is an addon to a windows phone project..so basically start the windows phone project and on the way decide if you want to add the toolkit based on your needs..the silverlight toolkit add some great controls like the wrap panel etc..so again its not that you can compare these 2