# Why can't I use the Windows.Phone.Media.Capture namespace?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm attempting to use the `AudioVideoCaptureDevice` namespace in my application however I can't seem to locate the namespace. My guess is that I'm missing an assembly reference but I'm unsure if this should be required. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and building against the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You say `AudioVideoCaptureDevice` is a namespace, and in the example, you use `private AudioVideoCaptureDevice av` which of course wouldn't work because you can't have an instance of a namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AudioVideoCaptureDevice` is available for use in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 Apps.
You created Windows Phone 8.1 Store App which uses WinRT API.

Your main two options are:

1. Create new project and use Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1
2. Leave your project as it is but use `MediaCapture` class of `Windows.Media.Capture` namespace instead of `AudioVideoCaptureDevice`

There is code sample available [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622/). It demonstrates how to use Media Capture API in Window Store App (it is for Windows 8.1 not for Windows Phone 8.1 but large part of API is shared between them and as such, this can be adapted for use in Windows Phone 8.1 App).

You might also want to read more about this subject because there are more differences between these two APIs.

- [Difference between Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012642/difference-between-windows-phone-8-1-and-windows-phone-silverlight-8-1)
- [Difference between Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055786/difference-between-windows-phone-silverlight-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-developme)
- [What is the difference between Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857490/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-phone-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-silverlig)
- [In windows phone 8.1 what is the differance between Windows phone project and silverlight project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544762/in-windows-phone-8-1-what-is-the-differance-between-windows-phone-project-and-si)